# How to know what color of paint was used on the walls?

Tags: painting

We've recently moved into our new house and we don't know which color the previous owner used to paint the interior walls. We've been trying to get hold of the previous owner but since he was only the seller, he didn't really reside in the house and he can't give us an answer.

Is there any easy way to know which color he used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a paint chip from a hidden location to the store, they will match it for you. It's a fairly common practice. Just realize that paint fades, so even a perfect match to your chip may not be a perfect match to the entire wall. It's best to paint at least up to a corner, if not the entire room. If that's not possible, then practice blending your patch into the rest of the wall by going over it with a mostly dry roller and a light touch.

Comment: Even then it's a crap shoot. There's often subtle differences in finishes between brands that can show up glaringly in the right light. I'd suggest just waiting to repaint the entire wall.

Comment: In my experience, painting the entire wall (up to corners/edges) is often less work than trying to get it to match -- especially because if it's *close* but not a 100% match, you can't tell until the next day when it's dried.

Comment: I took a chip from the wall and they matched it with 0.06% deviation and it worked very nice. It was not the exact color but since I just did some touch-ups it was not really important to me. You can recognize it when you look at it carefully.